# Error: LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS on windows machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, bluetooth

I was using noble node module to connect to blue-tooth devices, my code works perfectly on a mac machine, but I am facing some issues on a windows machine. I followed all the steps suggested by noble team here https://github.com/noble/noble#windows

But I face this error, any ideas why this is happening?

```
this.__open()
     ^
Error: LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS
at Device.usb.Device.open (C:\Users\Temp\Desktop\proj\node_modules\usb\usb.js:33:7)
at BluetoothHciSocket.bindUser (C:\Users\Temp\Desktop\proj\node_modules\bluetooth-hci-socket\lib\usb.js:73:19)
at BluetoothHciSocket.bindRaw (C:\Users\Temp\Desktop\proj\node_modules\bluetooth-hci-socket\lib\usb.js:28:8)
at Hci.init (C:\Users\Temp\Desktop\proj\node_modules\noble\lib\hci-socket\hci.js:101:35)
at NobleBindings.init (C:\Users\Temp\Desktop\proj\node_modules\noble\lib\hci-socket\bindings.js:82:13)
at Noble.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Temp\Desktop\proj\node_modules\noble\lib\noble.js:57:24)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I was apparently using the wrong libusb driver.

Using [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) I swapped to the `WinUSB` driver for the devices I was trying to talk to and then I stopped getting these unexpected `LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS` errors. I think the `libusb*` drivers work as well.

Comment: I tried using **Zadig** but it always gets aborted after some time. Any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: If it partially works, or breaks after some amount of time working, that sounds like a software implementation issue that changing drivers would not fix. Update software to use the newer libusb-1.0 api. It is compatible with more USB drivers (WinUSB and libusb0) so things "just work". There is even a compatibility layer so code doesn't have to change - just need to link to the newer dll.